# Wie nennt man das Satzzeichen, das in Tabellen eine Wiederholung markiert?

Tags: punctuation

In Tabellen findet man manchmal folgende Vereinfachung:

```
Artikel              Versand   Gewicht
=======================================
Schrauben             Paket    500g
Muttern                 "       "
Unterlegscheiben        "       "
Boxen                   "      300g
```

Wie nennt man dieses Gänsefüßchen (`"`) und weiß man etwas über seine Herkunft? Gibt es Regeln, wann dieses Zeichen eingesetzt werden darf (und wann nicht)?

Comment: siehe auch http://de.etc.sprache.deutsch.narkive.com/3WtCdmh6/anfuhrungszeichen-als-abkurzung-einer-wiederholung

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das nennt sich *Unterführungszeichen*. Die Richtlinien für den Schriftsatz des Dudens sehen vor, keine Zahlenangaben (einschließlich abgekürzten Maßeinheiten) zu unterführen; das Beispiel mit *500 g* ist also nicht korrekt.

Ebenfalls gemäß Duden-Richtlinien werden als Unterführungszeichen die öffnenden Gänsefüßchen (Neunen unten: *„*) benutzt, in der Schweiz allerdings die (dort) schließenden Guillemets (nach rechts weisend: *»*). Stehen die richtigen Zeichen nicht zur Verfügung, kann man auf `"` ausweichen.

Zur Herkunft des Zeichens ist mir nichts bekannt. Auch [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unterf%C3%BChrungszeichen) äußert sich nicht dazu.

Comment: Cool - jetzt da ich weiß, wie es heißt, eröffnet sich die weite Welt der Google Suche. Danke!!!